# Handling errors in Python in the console

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

I am currently working with a program and doing a lot of testing on it. I am using the Python logging library and write all my errors to the library. However, the errors also print directly to the console and show the entire stack trace which I do not want. Instead I would rather it just simply say error in the console and print out to the error logs.

I found this similar question here ([How to make python gracefully fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497952/how-to-make-python-gracefully-fail)) but all answers talked about using try catches. Is there anyway to set up errors being handled this way throughout the entire program without using try-catches? I foresee them being difficult to use, for example when I quit using `Control + C`, which I could do at any time and may not be able to catch in a try-catch block. I would love to be able to tell my program to handle errors a certain way and have that reflected throughout the entire program.

Comment: Wrapping your `__main__` block in a `try/except` is the idiomatic way to silence stacktraces. That said, a log aggregator like Sentry should be really useful, as it records stacktraces - most of the time you can avoid running a debugger in order investigate the problem further.

Comment: @JoshKopen what about `sys.stderr =  open('file.txt', 'w')` ?

Comment: `try/except` is *the* accepted way to handle exceptions in Python. And, as the Zen of Python says: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."